# $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} |\vec{v}-\vec{V}|(\vec{v}-\vec{V}) d t$, with $\vec{v}=(\vec{i} \cos t +\vec{j} \sin t) (\sqrt{1-p^2 \cos^2 t}+p \sin t)$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, vector-analysis, approximation

I need to solve this integral:

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} |\vec{v}-\vec{V}|(\vec{v}-\vec{V}) d t$$

$$\vec{v}=(\vec{i} \cos t +\vec{j} \sin t) \sqrt{1-p^2 \cos 2 t+2 p \sin t \sqrt{1-p^2 \cos^2 t}}=$$

$$=(\vec{i} \cos t +\vec{j} \sin t) (\sqrt{1-p^2 \cos^2 t}+p \sin t)$$

Here $\vec{V}$ is a constant vector (independent on $t$), $\vec{i}, \vec{j}$ are unit vectors of Cartesian coordinates, $p<1$ is a parameter.

To clarify, I've already done the following two things - solved it numerically using Mathematica and expanded it into Taylor series for small values of $p$, integrating several terms of the series.

> I want to know if there is some way to simplify this integral, or obtain some approximation for small values of $p$, not relying completely on Taylor series. Any suggestion would be welcome.

I know, that the first good approximation for small $p$ would be:

$$\sqrt{1-p^2 \cos 2 t+2 p \sin t \sqrt{1-p^2 \cos^2 t}} \approx \sqrt{1-p^2 \cos 2 t+2 p \sin t}$$

---

**Edit**

Thanks to Martin's comment, I now edited the title. Some further simplification would be nice.

Comment: $1-p^2 \cos 2 t+2 p \sin t \sqrt{1-p^2 \cos^2 t}=(\sqrt{1-p^2 \cos^2 t}+p\sin t)^2$

Comment: Wow, was I acting silly or what? Thank you very much